# Как передать массив в функцию? c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Как напрямую передать массив в функцию в [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)? На примере [java](/questions/tagged/java) это выглядело бы следующим образом:

```
void arraySetter(float[] array) {
    this.array = array;
}

arraySetter(new float[] {1.2, 2.53, 6.23});
```

В c++ я делаю подобное в одном из классов, пусть это будет `SomeClass`:

```
void SetArray(float array[]) {
    this->array = array; //error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘float*’ to ‘float [0]’
}
```

А вызываю (Скорее всего не правильно):

```
some_class_pointer->SetArray(new float[5]{2.4, 1, 0.76, 0.54, 0.33})
```

Comment: а что именно вы хотите сделать. Просто в `C` в отличии от `Java` у массива вы никак не узнаете размер. Поэтому есть смысл задуматься что именно надо. И да, как вы в классе объявили `array`? если как `float *` то скомпилируется а если как `float[]` то это само по себе не сильно правильно и значит другое.

Comment: @pavel, `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`?

Comment: В С++ встроенные массивы очень ограничены по возможностям, поэтому удобнее использовать std::vector, который знает свой размер.

Comment: @Herrgott это работает до первой передачи в функцию. В функции `type[]` преобразовывается в `type *` (можете проверить).

Comment: @vladimir хорошо, можете пример в ответ написать? С передачей массива в сырую, так скажем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С использованием вектора:

```
// Это поле вашего объекта, которое будет хранить массив, передаваемый в SetArrray
std::vector<float> Foo::array;

// Это метод, который принимает массив для сохранения в поле array
void Foo::SetArray(const std::vector<float>& array) {
    this->array = array;
}

// Это вызов SetArray который установит массив
some_class_pointer->SetArray({2.4, 1, 0.76, 0.54, 0.33})
```

Ну а дальше используйте поле `array`, например получите первый элемент как `array[0]`, или размер массива как `array.size()`.

Как бонус - никаких ручных new/delete и потенциальных утечек памяти.

Comment: я бы всё же по ссылке передавал...

Comment: @pavel, конечно, опечатался

Comment: @VladimirGamalian при вызове SetArray явное указание типа - лишнее. достаточно SetArray({2.4, 1, 0.76, 0.54, 0.33})

Comment: @gbg верно, хотел показать что там может быть переменная этого типа, но да, наверное лучше обновить.

Comment: А почему в аргументе без `const` не работает?

Comment: @Herrgott Должно работать. `const` только показывает намерение, что в методе вы не собираетесь менять передаваемый массив. Поэтому программист, посмотрев на сигнатуру метода, сразу сообразит, что передаваемому вектору ничего не грозит (он не поменяется).

Comment: @Herrgott а потому, что массив из аргумента - времянка (существует только во время вызова метода), и писать в нее нельзя. Хотите писать - убирайте и const и ссылку (&).

Comment: @gdb не обратил внимание на вызов, верно, без `const` не пройдет.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ничего общего с замечательным отладчиком GDB мой ник не имеет.

Answer (score 4):

Массив в C++11 бывает фиксированного размера `array` и резинового размера `vector`.

Оба массива лучше всего передавать по константной ссылке, если их модифицировать не нужно:

```
void foo(const vector<int>& arr);
void foo(const array<int>& arr);
```

Или просто по ссылке, если модифицировать таки нужно:

```
void foo(vector<int>& arr);
void foo(array<int>& arr);
```

Также, отличной практикой будет передавать не массив, а пару итераторов - на начало и на конец нужного диапазона:

```
void foo(const vector<int>::iterator& begin,const vector<int>::iterator& end);
```

Ну и пример того, что вы попытались сделать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using std::vector;
using std::ostream_iterator;
using std::copy;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void foo(const vector<int>& a)
{
  ostream_iterator<int> out_it (cout,", ");
  copy ( begin(a), end(a), out_it );
  cout << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    foo({4,5,6});
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/bvW6Hc)

Comment: а итераторы разве безопасно передавать? а если произойдёт расширение `vector` они же станут невалидные.

Comment: мне надо передавать элементы разного значения и разного количества в каждый объект этого типа, в котором функция. Кажется, этот ответ неверный

Comment: @pavel зависит от того, что вы собираетесь делать. Если обрабатывать данные в массиве - передавайте итераторы.

Если вам нужно где-то иметь указатель на массив, вам стоит сделать этот указатель умным.

Comment: @gbg, почему `begin` и `end` работают без `std::`?

Comment: @SergeyPestov - сам удивляюсь.